# Build errors in Accounts.framework header files

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode5

If I open my Xcode project and try to build I get errors on all file in `Accounts.framework`. This was not happening earlier. To fix this issue, I have tried reinstalling Xcode, but in vain.

Here's the error screenshot,

[image]

How can I resolve these errors?

Comment: It looks like it's caused by recursively including of header files.

Try to add @class Projec

Comment: Remove Accounts.framework and add it again...

Comment: Did you delete derived data. Clean project.

Comment: I try to test add @class in newest code and It's work.

Thank you anyone.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure in your build face --> link binary with library-->  accounts framework added. If it s there already remove and add it again.

Your issue is like you do not have reference of it.

[image]